# Why does my for loop only execute on the first item?

Tags: python

I have a list of regexes that I want to be matched against a file and the line number that the match occurs on to be added to a list specific for that regex.

```
regexes = [r"Repl ex\s+0\s+x\s+1", r"Repl ex.*1\s+x\s+2", r"Repl ex.*2\s+x\s+3",
           r"Repl ex.*3\s+x\s+4", r"Repl ex.*4\s+x\s+5", r"Repl ex.*5\s+x\s+6",
           r"Repl ex.*6\s+x\s+7", r"Repl ex.*7\s+x\s+8", r"Repl ex.*8\s+x\s+9",
           r"Repl ex.*9\s+x\s+10", r"Repl ex.*10\s+x\s+11", r"Repl ex.*11\s+x\s+12",
           r"Repl ex.*12\s+x\s+13", r"Repl ex.*13\s+x\s+14", r"Repl ex.*14\s+x\s+15",
           r"Repl ex.*15\s+x\s+16", r"Repl ex.*16\s+x\s+17", r"Repl ex.*17\s+x\s+18",
           r"Repl ex.*18\s+x\s+19"]


exchanges = [[] for i in range(19)]
# open the md.log file
f = open('myfile', 'r')


for x in range(19):
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if re.compile(regexes[x]).match(line):
            exchanges[x].append(i)
```

The above code gives the expected result for exchanges[0] but after that returns empty lists for the following 17 items.  If I run this with "1" in place of "x", I get the correct result for the next regex so I know the regexes are matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File handles keep track of where in the file they currently are.  When you iterate over `f` the first time (that is, when `x` is 0), `f`'s position is moved to the end of the file.  On subsequent iterations, there is no more text left to read.  What you could do is move the file handle to the beginning of the file at the top of the loop.  You can do this with `f.seek`:

```
for x in range(19):
    f.seek(0) # move the handle to the first byte of the file
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        ...
```

Comment: That's an interesting fix, thank you.  Right before I checked back I swapped my first two lines in the loop and that seemed to solve the problem too.

Comment: This is vital to know - solved a second problem I was having further down the script.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You've are trying to iterate over the same file over and over again using the same file descriptor. Whenever you read a line, the descriptor points to the next one in file. In the first iteration, the file will be completely read and the descriptor will have no more lines to read which is why your inner loop is not executed more than once. To resolve this, store your file contents in a list and iterate over that instead.

```
exchanges = [[] for i in range(19)]
# open the md.log file
f = open('myfile', 'r')
contents = f.readlines()
f.close()

for x in range(19):
    for i, line in enumerate(contents):
        if re.compile(regexes[x]).match(line):
            exchanges[x].append(i)
```